# virt manager - how to prevent mouse capture when using vnc

Tags: libvirt

I am running lineage os in kvm using virt-manager. When using the Spice Server, there seem to be problems with the mouse (its jumping around). So I am using the VNC Server.

When using Spice, I can prevent capture of the mouse by installing spice client in the guest (I don't know if that is possible with lineage OS).

But how can I archive the same when using VNC Server?
How can I prevent virt-manager to capture the mouse when using VNC Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I add a "Tablet" input device, the mouse is not captured anymore and I can use it in the virtual machine.